# Autonomous Mapping help!

Tags: slam, mapping, autonomous-car, ros-humble, nav2

I have a robot that uses odometry and Lidar.
Im using both Nav2 and slam_toolbox in order to manually create the map and then navigating through it.

My question is, Is there a way to make the robot map the room autonomusly? To know when the map is over and goes back home?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a bit of misconception with what SLAM does, just remember that SLAM stands for; Simultaneous Localization and Mapping, what you want is **to explore** the map (autonomously of course) so that while you explore it the map is built up, then the key term here is "exploration" (this is not a SLAM business). On the internet you can find many alternatives to explore environments, among the most popular you can find `rrt_exploration`, `frontier_exploration` and `ros2_explorer`.

Regarding going home when the map is finished, it is a bit difficult to answer since you must define or the library/package you use certain metrics with which you can consider that the map is complete.

I hope this answer sheds some light on your question.